# how to unset session on another device using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a website developed in Codeigniter. Now i need to unset the session of a basic user of my website from my master admin pannel. Somebody please help me to manage the session.

Comment: You can use the PHP `session_destroy()`, like this => `$this->session->sess_destroy();`. You will destroy the actual session of the user.

Answer (score 1):

This simple logout function will Destroy all the variable of the current session

```
  public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('redirectto/loginPAGE');
    }
```

or If you want something simple. This will remove only one variable from session.

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('USERNAME');
```

and if you want to remove multiple values from session. This will remove more values from session

```
$this->session->unset_userdata($array_items);
```

Source [codeigniter_session_management](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/codeigniter_session_management.htm)

Best practice would be save the sessions and make your own sessionhandler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$this->session->unset_userdata(session name);